# Recommanded cloud/cdn for my website?

Tags: web-hosting, cloud-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Currently we are using Cloudflare (Business) and it's great, except that our website is crushing for around 1 minute every 2 hours on average, and it seems they don't like to give us support.
So, we are looking for alternative. I thought about Incapsula.
Currently we have around 1mil pageviews daily.

Can you guys please recommand for us what to use/do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about Amazon's CDN, CloudFront? It's one of Amazon's Web Services(AWS) and given Amazon's infrastructure, I'd be willing to bet that that it would be reliable even at a million page views/day.

You can read more about it [here](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)

Comment: I have used Amazon until they went down for more then 24 hours in Virgina servers. I dont want to use them again, but if I will, can you estimate the cost for me? Last time our website, sql and everything was on Amazon and it was pretty expensive. Whats the price for Cloudfront only? Thanks!

Comment: @Tom you can find the pricing specific to Amazon CloudFront [HERE](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/).  It's all dependant on how many gigabytes you're transferring per month, not on how many page views you receive

Answer (score 0):

[MAX CDN](http://www.maxcdn.com/) seems to be one of the best solutions and many say good things about it.